# Reverse string with 5 consecutive characters

Tags: sed

I need to reverse all string in text with 5 chars consecutive characters. For instance:

```
hello hi adams sde
abcde abs
```

Required output:

```
olleh hi smada sde
edcba  abs
```

I used:

```
sed -n 's\(a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)/\5\4\3\2\1/p'
```

It reverses needed strings except "adams". Please help me fix this.

Comment: Why vote to close this? Might not be the clearest worded question I've seen, but I can't see how it can be described as "spam"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not so much that "adams" isn't replaced, but that your command is only replacing the first matching instance. Try this:

```
sed -n 's/\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)/\5\4\3\2\1/pg'
```

From the manual:

```
The s command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:
g    Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first. 
(snip)
```

Comment: you are almost right thank you:)
sed -n 's/\\([a-z]\\)\\([a-z]\\)\\([a-z]\\)\\([a-z]\\)\\([a-z]\\)/\5\4\3\2\1/pg'

Comment: so if you have a string like "powerful" , it will be "rewopful" ?

Comment: Adding word boundaries would prevent longer words from getting mangled: `sed -n 's/\b\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)\b/\5\4\3\2\1/pg'` (GNU extension)

Answer (score 1):

use awk

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(length($i)==5) {
            v=""
            for(o=length($i);o>0;o--) {
                v=v substr($i,o,1)
            }
            $i=v
        }
    }
}1' file
```

output

```
$ more file
hello hi adams sde
abcde abs
$ ./shell.sh
olleh hi smada sde
edcba abs
```